# Hoh to change arrow color/background color when hover

Tags: css, colors, hover

I would like to change both the background color (from transparent to #07b8b5)  and the color of the arrow (from #07b8b5 to WHITE) when hover the ss-go-top the button.

I can only change the background color of the button but not the inside arrow's color..

I am a beginner, please if something is missing to understand the question let me know and I'll clarify. Thank you)) –

Here the HTML and CSS code:

```css
ss-go-top {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #07b8b5;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8.4rem;
  right: 4rem;
}

.ss-go-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 6.4rem;
  width: 6.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  position: relative;
}

.ss-go-top a:hover,
.ss-go-top a:focus {
  background-color: #07b8b5;
}

.ss-go-top svg {
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.ss-go-top svg path {
  fill: #07b8b5;
}

.ss-go-top.link-is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="ss-go-top">
                <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0l8 9h-6v15h-4v-15h-6z"/></svg>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add hover style to SVG path** worked for me

```css
ss-go-top {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #07b8b5;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8.4rem;
  right: 4rem;
}
.ss-go-top a:hover svg, .ss-go-top a:hover svg path {
    fill: #fff;
}
.ss-go-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 6.4rem;
  width: 6.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  position: relative;
}

.ss-go-top a:hover,
.ss-go-top a:focus {
  background-color: #07b8b5;
}

.ss-go-top svg {
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.ss-go-top svg path {
  fill: #07b8b5;
}

.ss-go-top.link-is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="ss-go-top">
<a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0l8 9h-6v15h-4v-15h-6z"/></svg>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the arrow, in that element you only have to change the fill when the parent element has hover or focus...

example:

```css
 .smoothscroll {
        background-color: transparent;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .smoothscroll svg {
        fill: #07b8b5;
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .smoothscroll:hover {
        background-color: #07b8b5;
      }
      .smoothscroll:hover svg {
        fill: #ffffff;
      }
```

```html
<div class="ss-go-top">
      <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path d="M12 0l8 9h-6v15h-4v-15h-6z" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
```

this is to explain... in your case the solution would be to modify a little your css

```css
 ss-go-top {
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0;
        border: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-color: #07b8b5;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
        transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 8.4rem;
        right: 4rem;
      }

      .ss-go-top a {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 2px;
        display: block;
        height: 6.4rem;
        width: 6.4rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        position: relative;
      }

      .ss-go-top a:hover,
      .ss-go-top a:focus {
        background-color: #07b8b5;
      }
      .ss-go-top a:is(:hover, :focus) svg {
        fill: #ffffff;
      }

      .ss-go-top svg {
        height: 1.2rem;
        width: 1.2rem;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        fill: #07b8b5;
      }

      .ss-go-top.link-is-visible {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }
```

```html
<div class="ss-go-top">
      <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path d="M12 0l8 9h-6v15h-4v-15h-6z" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.ss-go-top:hover .smoothscroll{background: #07b8b5;}
.ss-go-top:hover .smoothscroll svg path {fill: #fff;}
```

Adding path works perfectly, thank you Jaswinder for your help :)

Comment: if my answer is worked for you please vote and  check answer it will help others too.